# Ajax show message on redirect

Tags: jquery, ajax, toastr

In my ajax call, if successful I want to redirect to another URL and display a message formed from [toastr](http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/).

Here is my ajax:

```
var redirectUrl = '@Url.Action("Index", "Informations")';

bootbox.confirm({
    title: "Delete?",
    message: "Are you sure you want to delete this?",
    buttons: {
        cancel: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-times"></i> Cancel'
        },
        confirm: {
            label: '<i class="fa fa-check"></i> Confirm'
        }
    },
    callback: function(result) {
        if (result) {
            toastr.options = {
                timeOut: 5000
            }

            $.ajax({
                url: "/api/Informations/" + btn.attr("data-id"),
                method: "DELETE",
                success: function () {
                    window.location.href = redirectUrl;
                    toastr.success("Successfully deleted");
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);

                    toastr.error(status + " - " + errorThrown, "Sorry, something went wrong.");
                 }
             });
         }
      }
  });
```

Now the problem is definitely the redirect before the toastr.success method being called.. so how do I display the success message on the new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the callbacks toastr provides, maybe `onclick` or `onHidden`:

```
toastr.options.onShown      = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl; }
toastr.options.onHidden     = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl; }
toastr.options.onclick      = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl; }
toastr.options.onCloseClick = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl; }
```

An example:

```js
$('.hej').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  toastr.options.onHidden = function() { console.log('I\'m hidden'); }
  toastr.options.onclick = function() { console.log('You clicked me'); }
  toastr.success('Have fun storming the castle!', 'Miracle Max Says');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/build/toastr.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://codeseven.github.io/toastr/build/toastr.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<a href="#" class="hej">Click me!</a>
```

In your case it could be something like:

```
<script>
  ...
  $.ajax({
    url: "/api/Informations/" + btn.attr("data-id"),
    method: "DELETE",
    success: function () {
      toastr.options.onHidden = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl; }
      toastr.success("Successfully deleted");
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
      var status = capitalizeFirstLetter(textStatus);
      toastr.error(status + " - " + errorThrown, "Sorry, something went wrong.");
     }
  });
  ...
</script>
```

**Updated**: If what you want is to show a message in the new page, where you've redirected, then you can do it passing that message as a parameter through the url:

```
toastr.options.onHidden = function() { window.location.href = redirectUrl + '?message=any_message'; }
```

And I've realized the options must be setted before the `toastr.success` assignation.

Comment: I have edited my code to what you have provided and I am not getting redirected after the success message

Comment: For some reasons JSFiddle doesn't reach the website when it has to redirect, but check this [pen](https://codepen.io/LagartoSeb/pen/oWBVMb) and check the console, it should work to test on your local machine.

Comment: just to be clear, I want this message to appear on the page that we are redirecting to, but I am still not getting redirected

Comment: Then you need to pass that message as a parameter to the url your redirecting. See the updated answer.

Comment: First, I just want to be able to get redirected after the message appears.. I'm not getting redirected at all

Comment: My fault, I've checked the options must be applied before calling the success on the toastr object.

Comment: Check this [git](https://gist.github.com/vnhnhm/a57df95f903fad3d4ba0e860de590e79), to see how it works, make sure to test it on your local machine.